# Typescript calling a function by reference inside of react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I am using Typescript with React JS.

let's say if I have a React functional component:

```
function MyFunction(){
      const myArrowFunction = () =>{
          return(
             <div>
                <p>Some Paragraph</p>
             </div>
          );
      };

     //In JavaScript, I would do this to call it the function by reference and it works.
     //In TypeScript, when I do the same, I do not see the "Some Paragraph" visible on the screen
     return(
         <main>
           {myArrowFunction}
         </main>
     );
}
```

calling the function with parenthesis works in Typescript:

```
return(
    <main>
     {myArrowFunction()}
    </main>
);
```

In JavaScript, I would do this {myArrowFunction} to call it the function by reference and it works.
In TypeScript, when I do the same, I do not see the "Some Paragraph" visible on the screen

What is the best way to call a function by reference in Typescript?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "call a function by reference"? The first example should give an error along the lines of "objects are invalid as react children" I would imagine (edit: just did a quick test with a umd version of react, it doesn't give an error in js but it doesn't output anything to the screen)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't change the fundamental behaviour of functions. At runtime, it doesn't exist _at all_.

Comment: The 2nd way works because is the correct way. Even in plain JS

Comment: You're treating that function like an eventListener where calling the function is implied. You have to explicitly call that function.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong even in `js`

I know what you want to do and you could call this as below, but it is not recommended to create a component inside a component

```js
function MyFunction(){
      const myArrowFunction = () =>{
          return(
             <div>
                <p>Some Paragraph</p>
             </div>
          );
      };
      
     // this is manly to stop typescript from complaining 
     const Fn = myArrowFunction as any;
     return(
         <main>
           <Fn />
         </main>
     );
}
```